# Unable to connect to Atlas cluster from Mongo Shell (Mongo shell version 4.0.10)

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to connect to cluster from shell. Error says that ip is not whitelisted, however, i have already whitelisted all ip.

Tried renaming password, as earlier it contained special character, but of no use.

Please refer screenshot attached.

mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-mgvvn.mongodb.net/test" --username

Error is inconclusive.[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNBK2.png)

Comment: It looks like the failed connection is being caused by the "Authentication failed" error message. Are you sure the username is correct? It looks like the username being specified is an email address; note that the username / password used to connect to your database is separate from those used to connect to your Atlas account. See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#add-mongodb-users for finding and creating a database user.

Comment: @AdamHarrison Thanks a lot pal. I used wrong username. Infact, while creating cluster i used different username and password, which i misunderstood as mongo atlas username/password.